# BitInstant "Bitcoin Address" option is down!

Tags: bitinstant

I want to cash deposit directly to my Bitcoin Address, but the option to do so has disappeared from BitInstant. Any ideas as to why? Do you think it'll ever be back?

Answer (score 2):

From what I heard browsing [/r/Bitcoin](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/), it might be due to BitInstant running out of coins in their hot wallet to fulfil transactions. However, this question would be best asked to BitInstant directly.

Answer (score 0):

We occasionally remove functionality from the site for various reasons but the functionality in question is usually returned to the site shortly after.

Comment: Are you a spokesperson for bitinstant? I don't see your name on the About Us page.

Comment: Yes, I am a customer support manager at BI.  You can see some of the BI team at https://new.bitinstant.com/abouttheteam

Comment: @URSAY, bitinstant website is blank